# How do Warding Bond and the Interception fighting style interact?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage-resistance, fighting-style, damage-reduction

So this interaction was with the Artificer Battle Smith in mind.

For [Warding Bond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/warding-bond):

> While the target is within 60 feet of you, it gains a +1 bonus to AC and saving throws, and it has **resistance to all damage**. Also, each time it takes damage, you take the same amount of damage.

For Fighting Initiate, Interception fighting style:

> When a creature you can see hits a target, other than you, within 5 feet of you with an attack, you can use your reaction to **reduce the damage the target takes** by 1d10 + your proficiency bonus (to a minimum of 0 damage).

Warding Bond is cast on the Steel Defender and an enemy attacked the Steel Defender.  The attack lands, then the Artificer uses their reaction for the Interception from Fighting Initiate.

1. Which effect takes place first?
2. How is the damage calculated (and eventually what does the Artificer take)?

Comment: I've closed your question as a duplicate of one covering general resistance and damage reduction. If you disagree, or feel like it doesn't answer your specific need, please let us know so we can reopen if necessary. Duplicates are also okay - it helps others find similar issues!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You apply the damage reduction first

This is covered on page 197 PHB:

> Resistance and then vulnerability are applied after
> all other modifiers to damage. For example, a creature
> has resistance to bludgeoning damage and is hit by an
> attack that deals 25 bludgeoning damage. The creature
> is also within a magical aura that reduces all damage by
> 5. The 25 damage is first reduced by 5 and then halved,
> so the creature takes 10 damage.

So, in your example, you reduce the damage first, than half it, and also take what is left over. Lets say like in the example, the original damage was 25 points, and you reduce it by 5 points with Interception. The remaining damage of 20 points is then halfed by the resistance from Warding Bond, leaving 10 points, and the Steel defender takes 10 points of damage. As you take the same amount of damage, you also take 10 points of damage.